# formating/quoting string in kable table

Tags: r, format, knitr

I am trying to format a `kable` table column to surround the strings with quotation marks. My problem is, I can not distinguish labels, if they have a trailing or leading space or similar problems.

```
library(knitr)
kable(as.data.frame(table(c('',' ',' '))), format='html')
```

My preferred output would be something like this:

```
|Var1 | Freq|
|:----|----:|
| " " |    3|
|  "" |    5|
```

Comment: Can you just add quotes with paste? `df$Var1 <- paste0('"',df$Var1,'"')`

Comment: I update my code to the use case. I didn't plan to save the intermediate result but wanted to use a quick one line code. But yeah, maybe you are right, it might be better to save in a variable and modify the text there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to NicE I created a little function which solves the problem.

```
myKableCount <- function(x) {
  df <- as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  df[[1]] <- paste0('"', df[[1]], '"')
  kable(df)
}
```